# `Score.skipTypesetting` and multi-measure rests

Tags: lilypond

I want to produce a version of a score where a few bars are snipped off, using `Score.skipTypesetting` as in the following example:

```
cuts = {
  s1
  \set Score.skipTypesetting = ##t
  s1*2
  \set Score.skipTypesetting = ##f
}
clarinet = \relative {
  c'1 cis d dis e
}
trombone = \relative {
  R1*5
}

\score { \new StaffGroup <<
  \new Staff << \cuts \clarinet >>
  \new Staff << \cuts \trombone >>
>> }
```

However, this produces an incorrect multi-measure rest in the part which has rests
(a 3-bar rest under the 1-bar `c'`, followed by two correct 1-bar rests). I understand that the multi-measure rest is typeset before Lilypond stops typesetting the staff; however, I could not find how to prevent this (I tried e.g. using `\Score.skipBars = ##t` or slightly displacing the `skipTypesetting` commands).

Is there a way to “cleanly” remove those measures?

[image]

The intended use case is that of a full orchestra score (e.g. full opera-size), where it will not be possible in practice to insert the `skipTypesetting` properties in each individual part; moreover there will be several such cuts. Also, I need to keep the source for these measures, since this is for a separate, abridged version of the piece. (Besides, removing those individual measures from the source would also be infeasible in practice at this scale).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a skipped grace to allow for typesetting of the bar and to suspend counting of time (to not count skipped measures):

```
cuts = {
  \omit Score.StaffEllipsis
  s1
  \grace { s1024 }
  \set Score.skipTypesetting = ##t
  \cadenzaOn
  s1*2
  \cadenzaOff
  \set Score.skipTypesetting = ##f
  \grace {}
}
clarinet = \relative {
  c'1 cis d dis e
}
trombone = \relative {
  R1*5
}

\score { \new StaffGroup <<
  \new Devnull \cuts
  \new Staff \clarinet
  \new Staff \trombone
>> }
```